# Using Fuzzy Lookup in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

In SSRS, let's say I have two tables. For example, I have:

TABLE1

```
AvgValueLow | AvgValueHigh | Rate
-----------------------------------
7           | NULL         | 3
4           | 6.99         | 2
2           | 3.99         | 1
NULL        | 1.99         | 0
```

And, then, I have a table that has:

TABLE2

```
LastName    | FirstName    | Value
-----------------------------------
Johnson     | Mike         | 4.5
Wright      | Dennis       | 3.3
Morgan      | Ferris       | 1.7
```

Now, I have no fields in-common between these tables, as they exist in completely separate data tables in SSRS. Furthermore, I need to be able to take the VALUE field from Table2 and look up what "range" it falls between in Table1 (for example, in Table2, Mike Johnson, with a value of 4.5, would land between 4 and 6.99 on Table1, so the function should return a Rate of 2).

If there isn't an easier way to do this, I can hard-code the values from Table1 into a function that will return the correct value, but I want to be able to leave the option open of changing the ranges/values in Table1 and not having to change the code that points to it.

Any suggestions or advice, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT t2.*, t1.Rate
FROM TABLE2 t2
JOIN TABLE1 t1
  ON t2.[Value] >= COALESCE(AvgValueLow, 0) 
 AND t2.[Value] <= COALESCE(AvgValueHigh,10000000)  -- set max possible value
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/IRNO81453)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ FirstName ║ LastName ║ Value ║ Rate ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬═══════╬══════╣
║ Mike      ║ Johnson  ║ 4,50  ║    2 ║
║ Dennis    ║ Wright   ║ 3,30  ║    1 ║
║ Ferris    ║ Morgan   ║ 1,70  ║    0 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

**EDIT:**

Your ranges will skip values from `1.99` to `2.00` like `1.995`. If it is the case you could search using only first value:

```
WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT t2.FirstName, t2.LastName, t2.[Value],  MAX(AvgValueLow) AS AvgValueLow
  FROM TABLE2 t2
  JOIN TABLE1 t1
    ON t2.[Value] >= COALESCE(t1.AvgValueLow,0)
  GROUP BY t2.FirstName, t2.LastName, t2.[Value]
)
SELECT c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.[Value], t1.Rate
FROM cte c
JOIN TABLE1 t1
  ON c.AvgValueLow = t1.AvgValueLow
  OR (c.AvgValueLow IS NULL AND t1.AvgValueLow IS NULL)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](http://rextester.com/GNF42015)**</kbd>

*Warning: I assume there is no gaps in ranges*

Comment: Ooooh. Elegant. I like it. Thank you!